# apt-get install giving 404

Tags: apt, aptitude

I'm something of a ubuntu newb. I'm trying to get subversion, so I enter:

```
apt-get install subversion
```

I'm getting a 404 on subversion and all its dependencies. E.g.

Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/subversion/subversion_1.4.4dfsg1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb

I've checked and that URL is indeed broken. Rather http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/subversion/ has versions 1.4.6, 1.5.1, 1.6.5 etc.

As I understand it, in order to get 1.4.4 I should find a mirror with 1.4.4 and include it in my sources.list file. (Is this correct?)

However what if I want to keep my current mirror and get one of the subversion versions listed on this mirror. I've tried

```
apt-get install subversion=1.6.5
```

but I get E: Version '1.6.5' for 'subversion' was not found

So, my question is, how can I tell apt I want to get subversion 1.6.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting a 404, it means that the file in question is not on the server. This probably means that your local package list is out of date. Update it with

```
apt-get update
apt-get install subversion
```

To see what versions of a package are available for installation on your system, do

```
apt-cache policy subversion
```

It'll tell you which versions of subversion are available for installation. It will also tell you which version would be installed if you don't explicitly ask for a specific version.

Comment: Hmmm, I run apt-get update and get a bunch of 404s as well. E.g.

Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/restricted Packages
  404 Not Found

Comment: gutsy is no longer supported by the Ubuntu project. I'm guessing that the repository has moved to an archive somewhere. Unless there is a reason that you want to stick with gutsy, I would suggest upgrading to either hardy (8.04 with long-term support) or karmic (9.10).

To do that, just edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change all occurrences of gutsy to whatever codename you want to upgrade to, then do `apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 2):

When an Ubuntu release becomes unsupported, it is moved to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.  If you change the host for all your gutsy-related repositories from `<whatever>.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` and then perform an `apt-get update; apt-get install subversion` it should all work nicely.