# Apt-get gives HTTP 403

Tags: apt

I've been given access to a server that no one uses... I've stated previously we are a research group that has no SA, therefore we blindly manage the servers ourselves... generally we break them or do something stupid.

So to the latest problem...

Whenever I try to install a package, something standard for instance like ruby (sudo apt-get install ruby) everything starts to load. But eventually I get an error saying the repository, or source destination will not give me access to the directory (Giving a 403).

Can anyone tell me how I go about redirecting to a repository that is accessible. The repository in question should actually be accessible.

Ideally I'd liek if someone can point me to a source file that has working repo's. We've been using HEANET from Ireland as our install dir, that always works on other machines!

I believe we are on ubuntu, the source file itself seems to be talking about Debian packages as well. I'm just after adding the output from the attempted installation. I've alreayd run apt-get update, this throws a variety of 403 errors as well.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
ruby1.8
Suggested packages:
ri ruby-dev ruby1.8-examples ri1.8
The following NEW packages will be installed:
ruby ruby1.8
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
Need to get 54.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 295 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
ruby1.8 ruby
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? Y
Err http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main ruby1.8 amd64 1.8.7.302-2
403  Forbidden [IP: 136.206.1.20 8080]
Err http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main ruby all 4.5
403  Forbidden [IP: 136.206.1.20 8080]
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby1.8/ruby1.8_1.8.7.302-2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 136.206.1.20 8080]
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby-defaults/ruby_4.5_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 136.206.1.20 8080]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: A lot of verse in the question and only little information. Which URL cannot be retrieved? What is the exact error? Did you try `apt-get update` first? What is in `/etc/issue`? Why not contact local support?

Comment: possible duplicate of [apt-get install giving 404](http://serverfault.com/questions/89128/apt-get-install-giving-404)

Comment: Added an update. The alternative question doesn't seem to provide a solution to my problem.

Comment: Please post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (transparent) proxy at 136.206.1.20 blocks your request. Look at the logs there, re-configure it, disable it or change the lines in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to the values that work on other computers.

`/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxy-ip:proxy-port";
```